# Tensorflow on windows 10

Tags: tensorflow

The docker image does not provide updated version of tensorflow. How should I upgrade to 0.12.0 cpu version?

I tried getting the latest-devel cpu version using: 
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -v /notebooks_proj b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel

but it is 0.8.0 version. How to get 0.12.0 docker?

Comment: By the way, if you are just using tensorflow without making changes to it. It is better to use the "latest" instead of the "latest-devel" tag. "latest" is a lot smaller than "latest-devel".

Answer (score 1):

The latest-devel and latest tags on gcr.io and docker hub should both be up-to-date (0.12.0-rc1 currently)

For gcr.io

`docker run -it --rm gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)"`

gives 0.12.0-rc1

For docker hub

`docker run -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)"`

gives 0.12.0-rc1